# How to add a LinearLayout in the same activity which has Listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have an Activity where there is a Linear Layout which occupies nearly half of the screen and below that I need to keep a listview which has hold any number of items. Now initially I was doing like this

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView>
    </ListView>
</ScrollView>
```

But reading all the threads I think it is not really a good idea keeping listview inside Scrollview. Also I am facing a lot of issues like the height of the Listview is not proper.

So how do I keep the layout and listview inside the same activity without using ScrollView?

Comment: can use tab if you want, `LinearLayout` in one tab and `ListView` in other or refer this [post](http://www.androidhub4you.com/2014/03/android-listview-into-scrollview-issue.html)

Comment: Can't you simply wrap it in another layout with `wrap_content` as the layout height value?

Comment: in that case, the LinearLayout will always occupy half of the screen and the listview will be in the remaining half. I want that when the user scrolls to the top, LinearLayout should also scroll so that listview can occupy the entire screen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not recommended to include a scrolling View (ListView) inside a ScrollView. What you want to achieve can be done by adding a HeaderView which can be inflated from another XML.

```
LinearLayout ll = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);
listView.addHeaderView(ll);
```